# Can I get the "It's Good" achievement once the "Recover ID Drive" quest has been accepted?

Tags: achievements, rage

Once I have accepted the "Recover ID Drive" quest, and then travel to the Ark, the Authority have blocked off the road near the bottom-level entrance to the Wasted Garage. This makes it impossible to drive the ATV close to the field goal near the Ark. Is it possible to score a field goal here later in the game? i.e. will the Authority road block be removed later in the game? Or is there some way to jump over the road barrier in order to get into the area between the Wasted Garage and the Ark?

- [Rage wiki on the Dam goal post for the "It's Good" acheivement](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/It%27s_Good!)
- [Rage wiki on the "Recover ID Drive" quest](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Recover_ID_Drive)

Comment: By the time I encountered this problem I had already completed the other two ATV jumps through field goals. This issue caused me to have to load up a very old savegame and then do all three ATV jumps in order to get the "It's Good" achievement. I would have prefered to wait until later in the game to get the last jump, hence why I am asking this question.

Comment: I don't have enough information for a full "Answer" but now that I can finally leave comments I thought I'd tell you what I know.  Neither [trueachievements.com](http://www.trueachievements.com/a155176/its-good-achievement.htm) nor [xbox360achievements.org](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=333348) list the "It's Good" achievement as being missable and those sites usually do a good job of letting you know.  I got all the achievements in one playthrough and my last story-related achievement was "ytiC daeD" so if you haven't gotten that one yet then there is a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can miss it

!SPOILERS BELOW!

Since the game ends when

> You wake everyone up in the other arks (I think they are called arks) you CAN miss this achievement.  If you save before you do this quest you can get it.

Source: Finished the game, restarted, got the achievement

Comment: So your answer is once you've finished the game you've missed it? Isn't that true of most games that don't let you free roam after completion?